# Deserializing exception while consuming from a Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

While consuming messages from a Kafka topic, I am getting the below exception repeatedly. Could somebody explain what the exception means and how to avoid it?

Exception stacktrace -

```
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TEST-TOPIC1.0-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 61
 Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:171)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:188)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:330)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:323)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:63)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndID(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:118)
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:121)
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:92)
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:54)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:65)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:55)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:918)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$2600(Fetcher.java:93)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1095)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1200(Fetcher.java:944)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:567)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:528)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1086)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043)
```

Comment: Did you read the error message or simply posted it here? Line 2 and 3 tell you that you are trying to retrieve from a schema that does not exist. If you [search on Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=Error+retrieving+Avro+schema+for+id) you get a lot of topics with solutions regarding the topic.

Comment: HI SaschaM78, yes you are correct. The error message says "Error retrieving Avro schema for id 61". But the question is how do we find the Avro schema of id 61 to which it is reporting as it is not finding. The case is that I published a messages based on a avro schema, and consuming using the same schema. But not sure how do we identify if the avro schema is different from the published one as it is reported by the kafka here. Specifically I want understand using the id how do we identify the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow issue details here
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/667

Optionally removing your kafka and confluent data folders can resolve this issue, if there is a missing avro schema